Calculating Length of Polylines in Miles Based on Individual Point Features
I am using ArcMap 10.8.
I may be trying to do too much in one query, but I'm hoping there is a way to do what I'm trying to do without repeating the process 1,657 times.
I am trying to analyze the distance of line that is downstream from individual devices on an electric utility network. There are 1,657 individual points in three different feature classes. Fuses, Reclosers, and Sectionalizers.
I could run trace by selection for each point and summarize the length, but 1600 objects might take a bit of time. I have looked into the Data Reviewer Extension but that seems to be able to analyze only by circuit since we don't have a field in the polyline feature class for upstream protection device.
I tried a Python script through the Python window, but that does the same thing, and I have to separate each downstream selection into a separate layer to analyze the table separate of the polyline feature class as a whole.
For visual reference the white circles labeled 30T in the photo below are fuses. I need the total length of all the line segments beyond that device, but for each device on our system.

Is there a solution I'm missing to take all the point features in one feature class, and use the geometric network tools to summarize the length of all the segments in one polyline feature class that are downstream of each point?
